# Neo4j traversal javascript api

Tags: javascript, neo4j, traversal

I'm trying to use traversal neo4j api rest in order to solve a problem like in the image

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3i9KFQXzB89YXl0VkEzaDZDMHc/edit?usp=sharing

I need to make a prune evaluetor based on a sum of precedent traversed node properties

It's possible to do with traversal api rest?
I'm searching for documentation but it's very poor in neo4j ufficial site.
I see only a couple of example that use position object ex:position.endNode() but without explainations.

My traversal is:

```
uniqueness:  node_path
max_depth: 6
prune_evaluator: (position.endNode().hasProperty('start') && position.endNode().getProperty('start') != '****');
return_filter: (position.endNode().hasProperty('name') && position.endNode().getProperty('name') == '***');
```

I'm searching to do something like this. NB: This syntax is completely invented:

```
prune_evaluator: var a = (int)position.endNode().getProperty('start');
                 var b = (int)position.endNode()->getParent().getProperty('start');
                 if( a > (b +10)){
                    true;
                 }else{
                    false;
                 }
```

Comment: Perhaps you can share the code you've tried so far, so that we can help you iterate on that.

Comment: I'm not sure if the javascript traversal API exposes the full path or just the last relationship, if the latter, you'd probably have to keep the other nodes in a variable yourself.

Comment: Tnx Michael for your attention! I have share my traversal and I made a pseudocode to explain what I need

Comment: I have also try with position.nodes().next().getProperty('start') but it seems that I can't use nodes object :  Access to Java class "java.lang.Iterable" is prohibited

Comment: I have found no solution and I decide to build an unmanaged extension with traversal